# MySQL and PHP tables with page hit counter

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a table that has the columns, page (the webpage) and count(number of times the page is accessed). How do i ensure the same page isn't added multiple times? i.e if a page is called index there should only be one row for the page index and all the hits in the column beside it.

To get the page name is use:
 `$info = pathinfo( __FILE__ );
$title = ucwords( $info['filename'] );`

to get the hit count i would use something along the lines of:
1. MYSQL query to see page already exists
2. If yes; get the count number and +1. If no; set count to 1
3. if 2 = yes; update count where page = page. if 2 = no; add to table page and count.

Would there be a better way to implement this as there will be anywhere between 5 to 15 pages that will have the counter.

Summary: Q1: How do i ensure the same page isn't added multiple times to the MySQL table?
Q2: Would there be a better way to implement this as there will be anywhere between 5 to 15 pages that will have the counter.

Thanks.

EDIT: Would this query work as a solution? `INSERT INTO pages_views ( pages_id, views) VALUES ( $page_id, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views=views+1`

Comment: Define "same page". Two differing records (i.e. with a different primary key - id) are "different pages" (rows) in your table

Comment: edited but here is the edit: if a page is called index there should only be one row for the page index and all the hits in the column beside it.

Comment: You have to define what a page is.  Ex. http://somedomain/page1.html and page1.html?somevariable=somevalue.  Is that the same page?  You might need to filter out some things out of the page to ensure they are the same, or not.  Other than that, you can increment the counter on the page you found, that's fine.

Comment: Set a unique key on one (or more) of the columns that you need to be unique. So, if you so not want a duplicate slug, something like `slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE` will do it when you define the table. This will return an exception when you try to use the same slug twice

Comment: @DanWhite would the new edit with the query work?

Comment: Probably but in reality you'll probably want something more meaningful than `/index`, `/index1`, `/index2`, etc. I'd catch the exception and return a message to the user to chose another ~**insert unique entity name here**~.